# How to get the hyperlink with PHP DOM?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I have a simple HTML construct:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="myStyle">
      <a href="URLa">Name of URL a</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="myStyle">
      <a href="URLb">Name of URL b</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to find out with PHP DOM how to get this URL and perhaps the name.

```
while($table = $tables->item($i++))
{
    $class_node = $table->attributes->getNamedItem('class');

    if($class_node)
    {
        if ($table->attributes->getNamedItem('class')->value == "myStyle") {
            $links = $tables->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('a');
            foreach ($links as $link) {
                echo "<br>" . $link->nodeName;
            }
            //echo "Class is : " . $table->attributes->getNamedItem('class')->value . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

So far I can print out every row that has the class "myStyle". But I'm not able to get Access to any value or href from there.

I know XPath is much more convenient but I want to try it first with DOM.
In XPath I know my Position when traversing through the DOM. But here with DOM I guess I'm not at that position in my Loop I want.

Comment: I usually use var_dump or var_export when I'm close to the desired result to see how to get it.
I'd suggest doing a `var_dump($link)` first to see what te structure is.

Comment: EMPTY ... :-(
Also var_dump($links) is empty. The Screen is totally blank.

Comment: what happens if you start with var_dump($table)? How do you initialise the dom? Could you add that as a seperate code field in your question? The problem could lie there.

Comment: Shankar Damodaran gave the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceed like this..

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $tag) {
    if ($tag->getAttribute('class') === 'myStyle') {
        foreach ($tag->getElementsByTagName('a') as $atag) {
            echo $atag->getAttribute('href');
        }

    }
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
URLa
URLb
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/123538)